# How do I show a toast notification from a WPF application?

Tags: wpf

I am building a WPF 4 application and I want to display a message in a nicely formatted box in a separate window in the bottom righthand corner of the screen.

I really like the popup that Evernote has whenever the application syncs with the main server.

How do I do this?

Do I just create a new window in my application and new up window displaying my message and then use a timer to close it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found this solution to be wonderful for my applications:

http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon

Basically, this guy created a whole system to do what you are asking for and more.

Comment: Is there a way to use `wpf-notifyicon` to show multiple Custom Ballon tips?